# Какую Linux ОС выбрать для программирования?

Tags: unix, linux

Мне нужен

- доступ в интернет,
- програмное обеспечение типа php apache mysql,
- всякие редакторы типа эклипса и нет бенса,
- компиляторы,
- джава,
- скайп,
- возможность разобраться в ос linux, чтобы в дальнейшем при работе с любой не было проблем (в той же самой консоли).

В общем требуется что-то универсальное для разработчика и чтобы сильно не грузило систему. Еще вопрос по поводу kde и gnome: я не знаю, что лучше. Что посоветуете установить по своему опыту?

Зы На обычный сd если влезет, то вообще кул.

Comment: Вот когда начнете понимать между ними разницу с точки зрения девелопера вот тогда и будете выбирать. А сейчас не имеет смысл ломать голову над этим.

Comment: в убунте LAMP стэк устаналивается одной командой в консоли :]

Comment: Судя по вопросу, человек в мире линуксов абсолютный новичек. В таком случае, ставим Ubuntu (или лучше Xubuntu или Mint, чтобы не париться с Unity, хотя это уже дело вкуса).

Comment: @mikillskegg, а я вот использую Ubuntu 10.04 (там ещё Gnome 2).  
Xubuntu тоже ничё так.

Comment: Извините за очередное воскрешение постов, случайно наткнулся.  
Думаю, для любого кто хочет познакомиться с линуксом  будет полезно почитать [Linux. От новичка к профессионалу][1]  
Книга читается легко, не перегружено терминами, осилить можно за неделю, а статовой информации куча.  


  [1]: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/18569398/

Answer (score 3):

Отвечу на личном примере - так как мой предыдущий ответ удалил. Я , раньше, не разбирался в машинах - но очень ее хотел. И у каждого таксиста я спрашивал - какую лучше взять. И знаете что - все ответы были разными, информация, которую я получил была равна 0. Потом я изучил строения двигателя да и вообще машины в целом и после этого, только после этого читая характеристики машин и рассматривая их схемы - я сделал для себя выбор. Вы сейчас делаете то же что и я делал с таксистами. Второй пример запри 20 линусоидов в комнате и задай им этот вопрос - папу римского выберут быстрее, чем линуксоиды прийдут к общему мнению.  Точно такой же вопрос про програмирование и тд. Если вы программист действительно (хотя я сомневаюсь), то вы поймете. А если не поймете задайте еще один вопрос - какой язык лучше ... (тут можно даже список языков привести) и вы увидите что будет.

Comment: Но вот смотрите, я ж не спрашиваю, какую Windows мне установить?
потому что она 1 и хорошая, что хр, что 7. Но с Linux беда, нафигачили кучу инсталяторов и нет той самой первоначальной версии, как это например в виндоус или в маке. Т.е. виндоус 95, а потом пошло поехало. С Linux я не могу понять цепочку этих разработок.

Comment: Вы правда перед покупкой автомобиля изучаете ее схемы? О_о

Comment: да правда. Особенно, если Я в них не разбирался. Во вторых вин95 ни в коем случае не является прародителем вин 7. В третьих представьте, что винда это нашинский автопром, а линукс иноммарка - еще вопросы есть?

Comment: встречный вопрос - предположим вы хотите купить фотоаппарат. Но вот беда - вы в них не разбираетесь вообще. Ваши действия - задать вопрос, типа хочу фотик, с возможностью зума, с возможностью скачать фотки с него и тд... или вы для начала изучите немного теории о строении фотоапарата. Еще вопрос - даже если вам все в один голос скажу "Зенит - лучше всех" - вы возьмете его не в никая в полробности?

Comment: Самый лучший способ найти "свой" линукс - попробовать самому разные версии. Благо, это не автомобиль, который стоит от 10000$. Скачал, поставил, поработал. Не понравилось - снес.

Comment: согласен с вами... Но для того , что бы пробовать  - нужно что-то знать. Без знаний - что вы попробуете. Посидите по окошкам по клацаете и все?

Comment: Ну, я уже написал: для absolute beginner самое лучшее - убунту. Осваиваем основы и вперед по волнам. Кстати, удобство кликания по окошкам - не такая уж малозначительная вещь.

Comment: А консоль везде одинаковая. Как и основные принципы устройства системы.

Comment: консоль везде одинакова? ладно это опустим. Почему именно убунту? почему не майн, кубунту или также опенсьюз с федорой последней - у них у всех дружественный интерфейс. Рисккну предположить, что вы судите из своего опыта и собственных взглядов. Если я прав - то мы приходим к истории с таксистами - и ценна вашей информации равна 0. также как и моей, особенно если я начну нахваливать тут майнт.

Comment: об этом и был мой предыдущий ответ - который удалили. Что вопрос на самом деле очень глупый и детский. А кто круче терминатор или человек-паук?.

Comment: Так я же тоже написал, что минт вполне подойдет. Почему не федора или сусе - потому что они объективно сложнее, чем убунту, хотя и проще, чем генту или арх. Убунту (и ее дериваты) - ОБЪЕКТИВНО самый простой вариант. Ну, как объективно BMW лучше жигулей )))

Comment: я уже скачал все версии линукса
убанту убога
опен сус - его можно ставить с виндоусом 7? короче я не стал ставить
федора понравилась пока не глюкнула
дебэин - вообще не понравилась
сентос - нормально не загрузилась разочаровала

вот и остался выбор
либо опенсус если он устанавливается вместе с виндоусом либо линукс минт

это убогое офрмление линукса бесит, лучше бы ничего не делали не позорились так
консоль и то красивее

Comment: @gjhgfddjhgjhg, судя по вашим комментариям (IMHO) \*nix Вам противопоказан.

Answer (score 1):

Ставьте Ubuntu и не парьтесь, все, что нужно найдете в интернете и достаточно хорошее комьюнити убунты в России поможет решению всяческих проблем.

P.S. да и Steam от Valve тоже будет сначала на убунту )

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu linux](http://ubuntu.ru/) очень юзерфрендли, и все, что Вы перечислили в ней или есть, или очень легко поставить из репозиториев apt. Распространяется на CD, но есть и DVD версии. Для начала можете поставить просто Ubuntu со средой Unity, если она Вам не понравится, сможете без проблем сменить ее на kde, или gnome.

ps:// Сам везде где возможно использую ubuntu

Comment: А чем, CentOs от ubuntu отличается?

Comment: Не знаю, как минимум - названием :]]
CentOS вроде как основан на fedora linux, в то время, как ubuntu На debian linux. В свое время мне приходилось столкнуться с федорой, и как-то не вдохновила она меня. Убунта проще и удобнее имхо :]

Comment: Ну а у меня на серваках центос стоит, вот и на свой хочу её же поставить.

Comment: Ставьте, кто Вам мешает? Я высказал свое мнение, и Я его никому не навязываю :]

Comment: CentOS - это пересобранная RedHat с собственными репозиториями (естественно, кроме закрытых компонентов последней). Популярна на серверах, потому что использует подчас старые, но проверенные и стабильные версии ПО. Для установки на домашний комп не рекомендую.Если нужно работать с rpm-based дистрибутивами, лучше Fedora.

Comment: У меня негативное впечатление сложилось о rpm-based системах, увы :(

Comment: Мне федора тоже не очень... Но вот сама система rpm мне кажется кажется удобнее и логичнее, чем dpkg. ИМХО

Answer (score 0):

Если нужна система, заточенная под девелопинг, то тут я могу посоветовать ArchLinux - причина в том, что у него одни из последних версий пакетов в стабильной ветке. Ещё одна особенность пакетов (конкретно - библиотек) - пакет содержит свою `-dev` часть, которую в ubuntu/debian обычно приходится ставить отдельно. Если лень ставить ArchLinux - ставьте Manjaro - тот-же арч, но уже настроенный и с DE.

Comment: Лел, некропостинг

Comment: Да и вопросы подобные уже больше года как оффтопик. Этот как-то пропустили )

Comment: Вот лучше не надо последние версии пакетов, а то потом на том же старом дебиане может взять и не запуститься